# Displaying TextBox after a certain button is clicked in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want an empty panel when clicked on in it a text box should appear on the same panel.This entire code should be in angular.

Comment: Hey @RPR you are new here I can see that. So when you ask the question you have to share some work or any code snippet that you have worked so far on so the community can help you better. Kindly share the work that you have tried so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-idhszt)   as a way create variable as clicked as default false in component.ts

```
isClicked=false;
```

give button a `(click)="OnClick()"` event

in component

```
OnClick(){this.isClicked=true;}
```

in html give element `*ngIf="isClicked"` to do it

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript:

```
showTextBox: boolean = false;

toggleTextBox() {
    this.showTextBox = !this.showTextBox; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel" (click)="toggleTextBox()">   
    <input *ngIf="showTextBox"> 
</div>
```

Set a boolean to true when you click the panel to show the text box and the opposite when you want to hide it.

The *ngIf in the HTML determines whether the text box is displayed depending on the value of the boolean.